# I enabled certain page view (which is a clone of currently working view), but its page link returns 404 page

Tags: views

The view is enabled, but its page returns 404. in what cases can such problem exist?

Comment: have you changed the path for cloned view

Comment: yes, I had changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the views and then in `admin/config/development/performance` do `clear cache`

Comment: @Lambrusco.Newbie your welcome :)